# Why does my new NPM React Component get an "Element type is invalid" error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, module

I'm trying to take a React library I'm using and moving it to its own NPM module.  I can import the component and build it in with webpack, but when I use it, I get this error:

"Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

The imported module looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PanelSet from './panelset';
import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';

class Mobinge extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const ratio=.75;
    const width = parseInt(props.width);
    const startPanel = parseInt(props.startPanel);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: width,
      height: width/ratio,
      startPanel: startPanel - 1,
      manifest: props.manifest
    };
  }
```

You can see the whole thing at https://github.com/samguyjones/mobinge/blob/master/src/mobinge.js

The importing code looks like this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Mobinge from 'mobinge';
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'


const Reader = ({match}) => {
  const panelNo = (match.params.panelNo) ? match.params.panelNo : 1;
  return <div>
      <Mobinge width="320" maxPanel="4" arrowThreshold="2" startPanel=        {panelNo}
      manifest="manifest.json"/>
    </div>;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const mobinge = <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/panel/:panelNo" component={Reader}/>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Reader}/>
    </div>
  </Router>;
  ReactDOM.render(
    mobinge,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
});
```

At the end of Mobinge, I export it with

```
export default Mobinge;
```

Originally, I started it with

```
export default class Mobinge extends React.Component {
```

with the same problem.

The import looks good to me.  If I put a breakpoint in Reader, it tells me that Mobinge is an empty JS object.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is something wrong with your npm package [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DisloyalNeatAbalone)

Comment: have you exported Mobinge ?

Comment: as default? I mean

Comment: Yikes @Sujit.Warrier, you're right.  I forgot to put the lines where I wrote the export into the ticket.  I've added them.  I'm exporting it.  I pulled the wording from this blog post https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

Comment: That narrows it down, @norbertpy.  This is my very first NPM package (I probably should have started smaller).  What things can go wrong with NPM?  What can I do to narrow this down?